# At what point in the Star Wars timeline do Mon Mothma and Gial Ackbar meet for the first time?

Tags: star-wars

When I see Mon Mothma and Admiral Ackbar together in *Return of the Jedi*, it seems to me like they have known each other for years. Yet, I have not seen Mon Mothma and Gial Ackbar together in any of Prequel movies or series. I have done numerous searches, and I haven't found any material that shows when these two meet for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

According to *[The Official Star Wars Fact File #3](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_3)*, Ackbar escaped from Imperial captivity somewhere around 5-6BBY, returning to Mon Calamari and fomenting a rebellion against the Empire. He was promoted to Fleet Admiral by Mon Mothma some time around 4BBY. This  is the first time that we have proof-positive of them meeting, although he was a Rebellion commander for at least a year prior to this and could easily have met her during this period.

> ...but secretly learnt all he could about his tormentors; studying their
> military doctrines and tactics, biding his time until he could escape
> and turn his knowledge against them.
>
> Ackbar's opportunity came when, on a trip accompanying Tarkin to his
> rendezvous with the first Death Star, the governor's vessel was
> attacked by Rebel forces. Ackbar duly escaped, and pledging to join
> the Rebellion, he returned to Mon Calamari to enlist the support of
> his people.
>
> **ASSET TO THE ALLIANCE:** Among the Mon Calamari's substantial
> contributions to the Alliance were their giant MC 80 star cruisers,
> some of the only Rebel ships capable of standing toe-to-toe with the
> Empire's Star Destroyers. Ackbar, now an Alliance Commander, also
> collaborated on the top-secret Project Shantipole. The goal was to
> develop a fighter capable of tackling much larger enemy capital ships.
> The result was the B-wing, the most heavily armed Rebel starfighter.
> **Upon delivery of the B-wing prototypes, Ackbar was promoted to Admiral
> by Alliance leader Mon Mothma.**

Comment: I still don't understand why the Mon Calamari aren't cephalopods...